# Why is the X-CSRF token missing from the header (intermittent)

Tags: authentication, oauth, csrf-token

We have an API to retrieve an X-CSRF token into our SAP System using oData Provisioning.

Prior to the call, we retrieve an auth-token which works fine.

We use the token in the X-CSRF

```
Authorization: Bearer (Auth Token)
X-CSRF-Token: Fetch
```

The API always returns a 200 OK return.

The problem is, around 50% of the time the X-CSRF-Token is not included in the returned header

Comment: Well either there is something going wrong with the call to retrieve the X-CSRF token and you have to solve it, or if this is expected behaviour write an if, fetch or whatever you prefer that says if you retrieve no token that you have to call it again.

Comment: Yes the retry seems to have provided a workaround.